# sorting for multi-character

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the sorting for multi-character. below is the couple for lines from the data.

```
data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
data

001@|@02@|@ABC@|@IND123
002@|@02@|@ABC@|@IND223
003@|@02@|@ABC@|@IND333
004@|@02@|@ABC@|@IND443
```

I am trying with the below code:

```
res = re.split('@|@',data)
print(res)
```

001@|@02@|@ABC@|@IND123

```
['001', '|', '02', '|', 'ABC', '|', 'IND123']
```

Please suggest.

Comment: what output do you want? probably you should do `pandas.read_csv('data.csv', sep = '|')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *escape* the pipe because in regex, `x|y` means `x` or `y`, so your regex splits your data at `@` or `@`. You can also specify the regex separator as the `sep` argument to `pd.read_csv` and have pandas split your data correctly as it reads it.

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None, sep='@\\|@', engine = 'python')

    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   ABC IND123
1   2   2   ABC IND223
2   3   2   ABC IND333
3   4   2   ABC IND443
```

Comment: I added an explanation because an answer that explains what's wrong is more helpful than an answer that says "do this"